# Create an OVA in VirtualBox where the disk is immutable?

Tags: virtualbox

I need to distribute a virtual machine to salespeople to run demos for clients. I'd like for the machine to be pristine each time they start it.

Currently I'm distributing a zipfile with the various vmdk/vbox files in it, but I thought it might be easier to distribute an OVA instead.

However, if you create an OVA, disk properties like 'immutable' seem to be removed.

How can I get around this?